# Cell look-up relating to value of another cell

Tags: excel

I'm developing a target tracking device for education and am a bit stuck. So far I've made a worksheet for each sub-level a child can reach and generated the childs target as the first not-achieved objective (value 0) for each sub-level.

I've also made a query to return which sub-level the child has fully achieved. I now need to make a way of generating the childs target by looking at their achieved sublevel and referencing the target column from the next sublevel.

I have tried this:

=if(F2=WT, [=Sheet1!AE2, =if(Sheet1!F2=1C, 'Level 1B'!AE2, =(if(Sheet1!F2=1B, 'Level 1A'!AE2, 0))

But it says the syntax is incorrect. Please can you help? I appreciate I'm a bit of a noob and have probably completely failed so please be patient with me!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put double quotes ("") around the textual parts.

also you need some rework on your parenthesis.

Lastly you only need to use = at the start of a formula unless you want to compare parts internally in your formula.

```
=if(F2="WT", Sheet1!AE2, if(Sheet1!F2="1C", 'Level 1B'!AE2, if(Sheet1!F2="1B", 'Level 1A'!AE2, 0)))
```

Comment: You are my hero! I'm taking the small victory that I had the right idea just the wrong syntax! I was starting to worry that I would need to use a Macro to generate it. Do you know how I would copy this formula down a column without having to change it each time? If need be I can change it as there's only 25 children in a class so I can change it on one and then re-save the master copy for each class.

Comment: You are most welcome. please mark the question answered so others won't have to dig into this.

Comment: You probably mean Sheet1!AE2  'Level 1B'!AE2  and 'Level 1A'!AE2 . To keep them pointed to the same cells you have to put $ signs in front of the letters and numbers: Sheet1!$AE$2  etc. The first $ stops the AE from becoming AD (left) or AF (right), the second stops the 2 from becoming 1 (up) or 3 (down). Now you can just drag this in all directions